# Are all the lambda argument automatically inlined in F#

Tags: optimization, lambda, f#, inline, inlining

This [post](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2010/12/performance-related-features-in-f-and-c.html) from F# News states that F# can inline a function passed as an argument. 
Is it always the case? Does it happen automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. If you have a function like the following, lambdas do not get inlined. 
In the following code lambdas are invoked using `FSharpFunc<,>.InvokeFast()`

```
let fold f s l = 
    let rec loop acc l =
        match l with []->acc |h::t->loop (f acc h) t
    loop s l

let list = [1;2;3;4]

list|>fold (fun acc x->x+acc) 0|>printfn "%d"
list|>fold (fun acc x->x*acc) 1|>printfn "%d"
```

But if you mark `fold` function as `inline` situation changes. Not only `fold` function gets inlined, but lambdas get inlined as well. I used .NET Reflector to confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what optimizations the compiler makes to higher-order functions, but this article seems to be referring to type-generalized functions explicitly marked `inline`. This is to support [statically resolved type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx).